# What FPGA development tools recommended for building audio music synthesizers?

Tags: audio

I want to experiment with FPGAs to build audio synthesizers. They would end up being manufactured in quantities of less than 100. I have very little knowledge of FPGAs, but I thought LabVIEW looks like the most intuitive programming option for a beginner. Another option is that I have a programmer friend who is learning OpenCL and keen to learn FPGAs.

I have built many analog synthesizers, and I have also studied simple digital hardware like counters, adders, shift registers.

I don't have this problem that other people seem to have about FPGAs, when they complain that it is not like sequential programming. I don't like the idea of using sequential programming to do real time audio. To me FPGAs seem more natural. This is a reason why I thought of using an FPGA with LabVIEW, as opposed to a microprocessor like the STM34.

Can anyone think of problems I am likely to encounter?

Comment: i imagine dev tools for FPGA are pretty extensive.  it seems to me that if you have very little knowledge of FPGAs, you would do better with a dev board with some kinda ARM chip on it or some DSP (like a SHArC) on it.  there are some stomp-boxes that you might be able to turn into a synth.

Comment: You you say that because a DSP is better suited, of because is would be easier to learn? I notice some audio companies use SHARC processors.

Comment: it's easier to develop mathematical algorithms on a MCU (like an ARM) or a DSP (like a SHArC) than it is to develop an algorithm of the same mathematical complexity on an FPGA.  far easier.

Comment: I just saw that Analog Devices SigmaDSP chips can be programmed using very user friendly visual software called Sigma Studio. They are also optimised for audio.

Comment: it's a IDE.  the assembly language is powerful, but quirky.  the C/C++ compiler produces atrociously poor-quality code.  if you're looking for an audio testbed, maybe check out Danville Signal Processing.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson I want to make a fundamental frequency detector for the human voice. Probably by doing an FFT of an FFT. Do you know what SHARC would be good for this, and what software and hardware do I need to get hold of to do this?

Comment: do you like programming in assembly?  i think that C-compiled code for the SHArC is poor quality.  but you need the VisualDSP IDE and possibly the JTAG emulator board.  but you might be able to load and run code without the emulator, but i don't think you can step through code without the emulator.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Not assembly, I am a beginner in programming. There is also their CrossCore software, I don't know how it differs from VisualDSP. Seems like CrossCore needs more add-ons, whereas VisualDSP is a complete package. Btw this may sound like a dumb question, but why would JTAG debugging be necessary? Surely if the software is designed with a specific device in mind, then the software should know how to spot bugs before it is sent to the device.